# Row-major order indices

Tags: dictionary, indexing, block, coordinate

I'm currently working on project of where 2d terrain maps are saved into a one-dimensional array. Each block in the map is indexed by xy coordinates. So, to save the map into a one-dimensional array, I used the row-major order method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) to convert the xy coordinates into a single index value (Which let me put the block into an array).

Now, my problem is how do I convert it back? I have a unique number which I have to convert back into xy coordinates.
Any help would be appreciated. ^^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To calculate indices you should be using something like this:

```
index = X + Y * Width;
```

So, to reverse this you can take advantage of integer division truncation to get Y, and then X is just what's left over after what Y "used up":

```
Y = (int)(index / Width)
X = index - (Y * Width)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. For example (0, 4) gives 20 and when reversed, 20 gives back (16, 4)

Comment: He has the right idea, I think he just made a typo.   X = index - (y* width);  So X is what is left over after you remove the Rows used up by Y.

Comment: Oops, this is what comes of answering questions when you've just got out of bed! Thanks for correcting me.