# How can I create this int value and process it?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

For example  I have these `int`s value.

```
int map1[10][10] = //;
int map2[10][10] = //;
int map3[10][10] = //;
int map4[10][10] = //;
int map5[10][10] = //;

for (int i = 1 ; i < 6 ; i++)
map{i}[2][2] = 3;
```

The above code just for illustration/understanding, I know it is wrong. How can I select/access my `int`s ?

Comment: Consider `int map[6][10][10]`?

Comment: Have a look at this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652598/2d-array-as-argument-to-function/12653518#12653518

Answer (score 8):

You are declaring a 2D array or an array of arrays filled with integers numbers `int map5[10][10]`, so to access those values you need to use this syntax, e.g. `map5[0][1]` refers to the second element in the first row.

__________________________________[image]

________________________________________[image]

If you want to easily use the different arrays, use a multiple subscripted array or a 3D array, but there are many other ways.

```
int map[5][10][10] = //;

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    map[ i ][ 2 ][ 2 ] = 3;
```