# Indexing elements in a 3-D array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

In the following code snippet:

```
int a[2][3][2]={{{1,2},{9,8},{3,7}},{{2,2},{1,4},{5,4}}};
```

what will be the answers for a[i],a[i][j] ,where i<=1 and j<=2
 I have no problem in understanding the a[i][j][k] working.Can you please explain how does the above indexing works?

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) helps.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Not really. I still cannot understand how , for example a[1]-a[0]=3 .But the article you linked is great.Thanks

Comment: `a[i]` is `int ** ` type `a[i][j]` is `int *` type and `a[i][j][k]` is `int` type so all three are different

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551168/how-can-i-create-this-int-value-and-process-it/13551183#13551183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you have to remember here is that the there are 2 different objects you are working with.

```
a[i][j][k]
```

and

```
a[i][j], a[i] and a
```

The first is an int, the other 3 are pointers

The associated memory's look like this:

```
a       : | a[0] | a[1]|
             \/     \______________________
a[]     : | a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[0][2] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | a[1][2] |
             \/         \______________
a[][]   : | a[0][0][0] | a[0][0][1] | a[0][1][0] | a[0][1][1] | ...
```

And so on...

Now in the example you make you do arithmic operations with pointers eg. `a[1] - a[0] = 3`. If you look at the memory associated wit that you can see there are 3 memory locations between the 2 pointers, thus the result is 3.

Comment: Very well explained .I didnt know that the later 3 forms are pointers .Understanding that helped me ,Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

I am not entirely sure what your problem is, but I will try to explain the indexing to you:

What you create in your example is a three dimensional array (or a nested array if you will).

I'm sure you understand simple arrays like the following

```
            ---x---
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Now when you request `a[x]` the x will determine which position of the array is chosen.

A two dimensional array is merely an array of arrays

```
                ---------y--------
                ---x---    ---x---
int b[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

When you request `b[y][x]` the y will determine which of the two one dimensional arrays is chosen and then the x tells you which position of that array.

A three dimensional array is only taking this one level higher: an array of arrays of arrays

```
                    ----------------------z--------------------
                    ---------y---------     ---------y---------
                    ---x---    ---x---      ---x---    ---x----
int c[2][2][3] = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} };
```

Now a request to `c[z][y][x]` goes to the z-th 2d-array, then to the y-th 1d-array of that 2d-array and then to the x-th position in this array.

The requests to `c[z]` or `c[z][y]` will only result in addresses of arrays and not yield any actual int values.

Answer (score 1):

a[i] and a[i][j] are addresses, it has nothing to do with the values specified in `int a[2][3][2]={{{1,2},{9,8},{3,7}},{{2,2},{1,4},{5,4}}};`. That means a[1]-a[0] is the number of bytes between the second array pointed by a and the first one.

Comment: I cannot understand what you meant by "the number of bytes between the second array pointed by a and the first one".Can you explain how a[i]-a[0]=3 and a[1][0]-a[0][0]=3 in the code?

Comment: Not the number of bytes, the number of memory locations. There are 12 bytes between 3 ints.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[0] = {{1,2},{9,8},{3,7}}
a[1] = {{2,2},{1,4},{5,4}}

a[0][0] = {1,2},                 a[0][1] = {9,8},                a[0][2] = {3,7}
a[0][0][0] = 1,  a[0][0][1] = 2, a[0][1][0] = 9, a[0][1][1] = 8, a[0][2][0] = 3, a[0][2][1] = 7

a[1][0] = {2,2},                 a[1][1] = {1,4},                a[1][2] = {5,4}
a[1][0][0] = 2,  a[1][0][1] = 2, a[1][1][0] = 1, a[1][1][1] = 4, a[1][2][0] = 5, a[1][2][0] = 4
```