# Finding Determinant of a matrix in C

Tags: c, determinants

This is the C code for determinant of matrix, But it gives compilation errors.

Code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int m;

float determinant(float b[][]);

int main(void)
{
int i,j,m;
printf("enter a no: ");
scanf("%d",&m);
//printf("%d",m);
float arr[m][m];
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&arr[i][j]);
        //printf("%f",arr[i][j]);
    }
}


for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        printf("%f ",arr[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}



float det = determinant(arr);

printf("Determinant= %f ", det);




}

float determinant(float b[][])
{
int i,j;
int p;
float sum = 0;
float c[m][m];

for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        printf("%f ",b[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}



if(m==2)
{
    printf("Determinant for m=2");
    sum = b[0][0]*b[1][1] - b[0][1]*b[1][0];
    return sum;
}

for(p=0;p<m;p++)
{
    int h = 0,k = 0;
    for(i=1;i<m;i++)
    {
        for( j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(j==p)
                continue;
            c[h][k] = b[i][j];
            k++;
            if(k == m-1)
            {   
                h++;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    m=m-1;
    sum = sum + b[0][p]*pow(-1,p) * determinant(c);

}




return sum;
}
```

And the Compilation Errors are:

```
det.c:5:25: error: array type has incomplete element type
det.c: In function ‘main’:
det.c:36:2: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
det.c: At top level:
det.c:45:25: error: array type has incomplete element type
det.c: In function ‘determinant’:
det.c:91:3: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
det.c:99: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/cc1Kp9KD.out file, please attach this to your bug report.
```

I think the error is in the passing of 2-D Array. when I passing it as a pointer then it gives warnings but no errors but it does not give the right result as in always gives determinant as Zero. So I guess the array is not being passed only and when I print it in the function determinant it doesn't print also.
Please help as I am stuck because of this in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2D-array as argument to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652598/2d-array-as-argument-to-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare array dynamically like this in C99 (variable length arrays, pointed out by haccks), but not in the earlier version:

```
float arr[m][m];
```

So, if it troubles you then instead declare a pointer and malloc memory for it:

```
float* arr = malloc(sizeof(float)*m*m);
```

Also, the definition won't work (in either case):

```
float determinant(float b[][]);
```

you need to define the columns in the array that you pass to the function.

If you declare and allocate the pointer as I have shown then you can just pass a pointer in your function:

```
float determinant(float *b, int size); //here size is your row dimension, in this case equal to m
```

And inside the function, access your elements like:

```
*(b + size*i + j) = value // equivalent to b[i][j];
```

Comment: Yes you can. This is called variable length array.

Answer (score 0):

in your code,

```
scanf("%d",&m);
//printf("%d",m);
float arr[m][m];
```

here  arr is a 2D array with static memory allocation so you can not read m at run time and declare arr like this.
so if you are want to define the array dynamically then use dynamic memory allocation methods like `malloc()` in C.

Comment: You answer is wrong. Read about variable length arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the prototype of a function as

```
int foo(int arr[], int n);
```

then compiler interprets it as

```
int foo(int (*arr), int n);  // and that's why you can omit the first dimension!
```

i.e, your function is expecting first argument is of type `int *`. Similarly, when the parameter is a multidimensional array as

```
int foo(int arr[][col], int n); // Only first dimension can be omitted. You need to specify the second dimension.
```

then the compiler interprets it as

```
int foo(int (*arr)[col], int n);
```

i.e, your function is expecting first argument is of type `int (*)[col]` (a pointer to `int` array).
Since when passed to a function (in most cases) array names decay to pointer to its first element, in your case `arr` will be decayed to pointer to its first element, i.e, first row. Hence its type will become `float (*)[m]`. Its is compatible to your function parameter if you will declare it as

```
float determinant(int m, float b[][m]);
```

and the call should be like

```
float det = determinant(m, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your array with explicit bounds `float b[m][m]`; the compiler doesn't understand empty bounds in `float b[][]` (empty bounds are OK only for 1-D arrays, for reasons explained in the other answers).

So your determinant function should look like this:

```
float determinant(int m, float b[m][m])
{
    ...
}
```

There are other ways to make your code work, but I think this way is closest to what you already have.

Comment: I tried this but doesnt work, and gives one more error as 'm ' undeclared? can u tell other solution

Answer (score 0):

I agree you can't move with this syntax of array initialization, u could have used

```
int *p=(int*)calloc(n*n,sizeof(float));
```

And then access your elements as :-

```
*(p+j+n*i);//for p[i][j] element
```

Hope it helps :)