# C++ Why do I get next row value when it is out of range in my multidimensional Array?

Tags: c++

Here is my code,

```
int a[3][3] ={
            {0,1,2},
            {3,4,5},
            {6,7,8}
    };
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++)
        for(int j = 3 ; j>0 ; j--)
            cout << a[i-1][j] << " ";
```

I expected the output to be  `"0 0 0 0 2 1 0 5 4"`
but it turns out to be `"0 0 1 3 2 1 6 5 4"`

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: What is the logic you have in mind to get `0 0 0 0 2 1 0 5 4` as output, for the given input?

Comment: Did you intend `cout << a[i][j-1] << " ";`? That wouldn't give you the output you want, but would prevent invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: @t.niese the way I understood it, it is right to left and top to bottom. Add a zero row at the top.

Comment: @t.niese the logic behind that is i assume undefined/uninitialized value as 0

Comment: In your `a[3][3]` array you have `9` values, so there are no undefined/uninitialized values in that array. And anything that is out of the bounds of that array can be anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the reason behind this?

First of all, out of bounds array access is undefined behavior. So your first access to `a` which is `a[-1][3]` is not valid.

But to your question what is happening there:

You can imagine your:

```
int a[3][3] = {
  {0, 1, 2}, 
  {3, 4, 5},
  {6, 7, 8}
};
```

to have this layout in your system memory:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Your `[-1]` in `a[-1][3]` points three elements before your `arr` array.

```
 arr[-1]     arr[0]      arr[1]
  ↓           ↓           ↓
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ? | ? | ? | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

With `[3]` in `a[-1][3]` you try to access the element at index `3` from that position.

```
  0   1   2   3
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ? | ? | ? | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

So the first value you see is the first element of your `arr`, the next two `a[-1][2]` and `a[-1][1]` are *"garbage"* values.

That's what happens on your system, but keep in mind that this relies on undefined behavior.

Comment: I believe that this question does not add anything over [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why). Also, you might want to link to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653518/9414470). Still, +1.

Answer (score 3):

See first 4 and 7th value in the output( `0 0 1 3 2 1 6 5 4` ) you are getting are garbage value and they can be anything. When i executed this code i'm getting `0 2 0 3 2 1 6 5 4`. It is because you are accessing out of bounds values for **a[-1][3], a[-1][2], a[-1][1], a[0][3] and a[1][3]**.

Comment: `a[0][3]` and `a[1][3]` are also out of bound accesses leading also to UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I see a bug in

```
for(int j = 3 ; j>0 ; j--)
```

`j` should start from 2 and not 3 as the indexing is 0 based. The condition should be `j >= 0`.

This should look like     `for(int j = 2 ; j >= 0 ; j--)`.

Or you could go for inner loop like

```
for(int j = 3 ; j - 1 >= 0 ; j--)
        cout << a[i-1][j-1] << " ";
```

But "0 0 0 0 2 1 0 5 4" doesn't make sense to me with the kind of looping you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

in the first loop, i is equal to 0 
and when you use

```
cout << a[i-1][j] << " ";
```

i-1 is -1 and I think this is your problem because accessing the -1 index of the array will cause undefined behavior